# nginx not responding to GET requests

Tags: nginx

nginx is not responding to any requests and I'm not sure why. Here is what my file in sites-available looks like (it is symlinked from sites-available):

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    access_log /srv/www/logs/access_log;
    error_log /srv/www/logs/error_log;
    root /srv/www/public_html;

    location / {
            index   index.html;
    }
}
```

If I try to access `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`, the browser (Firefox) just tells me that is "loading" for a very long time.

Nginx is listening on port 80 when I run netstat -lpn:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10952/nginx
```

I have tried to `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` and then typed the following:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 79.124.59.177
<blank line>
```

However, there is no response to this. Any ideas or suggestions? I'm completely stumped.

Comment: under what OS linux? if linux ubuntu/centos/fedora? anyway sounds like firewall issue try to `service iptables stop` again if linux.

Comment: That worked! So it must be a firewall problem. However, I have rule opening up port 80 in iptables. I'm going to edit the question with the details.

Comment: `/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`                    
`/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` will open it for you also for SSL(port 443) after hit `service iptables restart`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify Host as "127.0.0.1", which represent the name of server, and it should same as server_name in config file, I guess.